# How can I correctly manage my memory so I don't have problems?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory, memory-management

I have an app with 2 View Controllers, first has almost nothing inside, I only load JSON data there. But the second has a map which displays the current location and some pins downloaded from the json file. When I'm in my first VC the memory is ok (16.4 MB) but after I load the second VC, the memory jumps to about 93.9 MB, the problem is: when I enter the first VC again the memory is about the same ±10 MB but when I enter the second VC the memory jumps to 139 MB. If I still do this over and over my app will eventually crash because the memory is (extra) loading. I thing it has do with the fact that memory keeps adding when I'm entering a VC but how can I delete or manage it correctly.

here is my github repo:

https://github.com/octavi42/mapsApp

Comment: please use Xcode instruments to find out where the memory is being used heavily

Comment: I don’t have much experience with Xcode instruments, can you give me a link with some tutorials or you can look in my project, the github link is in the description

Comment: try https://medium.com/@kazmiekr/what-every-ios-developer-should-be-doing-with-instruments-d1661eeaf64f

Comment: There's a lot of things wrong with your code: you are not using MVVM, you have timer on main thread, your view controllers call each other and so on. Also from your comment it looks like you are looking for tutorials and code review, neither of which is suitable for stackoverflow question.

Comment: @KirilS. What I want is an answer to my memory issue questions but its true that I need some more experience in swift programming so if you have some advicees or tutorial they will be welcomed.

Comment: @OctaCZO when design has several major flaws, which I mentioned above, it's hard to pinpoint anything more specific. It could be any of the problems I mentioned that is causing a leak, or something else entirely, but currently hidden by more obvious problems.
So learn MVVM, get your code organized better, follow Apple's Performance tips (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/improving_your_app_s_performance) and then if you still have a leak, then you will also have a more concrete question someone can actually help with.

Comment: Got it, I’ll do what you mentiond and see if I get the same error   Thanks!

Comment: I didn't download your project, but from your question it sounds like you are presenting multiple VC instances I.e, AppVC->MapVC->AppVC->MapVC and so on. This will cause memory use to grow.  If you want to return to the AppVC then you should read up on unwind segues so that you can go back to existing instance and allow the MapVC to be released. You don't need anything as complex as MVVM; as a beginner this will just confuse you more, but you should separate your model from your view controller; even using MVC will help you.

Comment: @Paulw11 I tried unwinding segue and I think this might work but I have a problem, when I press the button that run the unwinding segue it unwinds and the screen turns black, without crashing

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, like @Paulw11 said, that I didn't unwind the segue, I performed the passing from VC 2 to VC 1 with another segue, this should be done with a unwinding segue, I did it and I hove no more memory problem, when I'm going back in VC 1 the memory shrinks to 20MB.